# Why the count number is different from both code, I think they have the same logic

Tags: sql

code 1

```
 WITH t1 AS (
        SELECT SUM(standard_qty) totsqty, a.name accname, SUM(o.total) total
        FROM orders o
        JOIN accounts a
        ON o.account_id = a.id
        GROUP BY 2
        ORDER BY 1 DESC
        LIMIT 1
        ),
 t2 AS (SELECT total
        FROM t1
        )
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM orders o
JOIN accounts a
ON o.account_id = a.id
HAVING SUM(o.total) > (SELECT total FROM t2)
```

This one shows results figure only 6170, but the correct answer is 3.
Another code is like this

```
WITH t1 AS (
        SELECT SUM(standard_qty) totsqty, a.name accname, SUM(o.total) total
        FROM orders o
        JOIN accounts a
        ON o.account_id = a.id
        GROUP BY 2
        ORDER BY 1 DESC
        LIMIT 1
        ),
 t2 AS (SELECT total
        FROM t1      
        )
SELECT COUNT(*), SUM(o.total) acctotal, a.name
FROM orders o
JOIN accounts a
ON o.account_id = a.id
GROUP BY 3
HAVING SUM(o.total) > (SELECT total FROM t2)
```

This one show 3 rows, which means only 3 accounts have higher number of orders.
Why the first code didn't show figure 3?
Help, please~~

Thanks in advance.

Comment: your frist query result in **one** row, your second in multiple, wihich are then checked, simp,ly both are not equal

Answer (score 0):

**t1** is showing the `qty` and `total` per `accname`, then ordering by the `qty` and finally selecting just the first one.

**t2** is showing the `total` for the account with the biggest quantity.

In the first example, the `HAVING` parameter at the bottom is basically saying "*Show me all the results where sum of ALL orders combined is greater than my biggest accname*", which will always be true. The sum of **all** will always be greater the sum of its parts.

The second example works because the final query is also grouping by the accname, so you're comparing parts with parts.

One way to check your results is not to count. Just list every row to check the results that you're counting.